# Support displaying emojis in UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7, emoji

I'm having problems displaying emojis in a UILabel.
in some cases, it even causes a crash when lay-outing the characters in the label.
these characters are returning from server as unicode, and are parsed with AFNetworking framework.

this is an example of how it is returned from the server (console logs):

```
\U05d4\U05d9\U05d9
```

i have tried different approaches, like lowercasing this to "\u05d4" or playing with the encoding of the string returning.
nothing seems to work.

i did managed to show a couple of emojis properly (which makes me think it maybe a server related issue?) - does the server needs to support sets of unicode characters so it can return it in the appropriate encoding? i'd be happy if someone could clarify this point for me. (btw, server is written in RubyOnRails i believe.)

should i parse the data with a different parser (SBJSON)? although switching the networking framework at this point would be impossible due to time and resources available..

what other options do i have?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think you should be able to just paste an emoji character in the code directly as a text.

Comment: I'm getting this info from a server response. "pasting" it will not help here. What i did was set the label's text as the response string - (which was the problem in the first place). is that what you meant?